# Cómo buscar palabras por clave en archivo .csv?

Tags: python

Buenas estoy creando un programa que ingresa: codigo,descripcion y stock.

No sé si lo estoy haciendo bien. En fin, el programa tiene que ingrsar los datos dichos previamente y buscar mediante codigo la: descripcion y stock. Segun el código escogido.

La verdad estoy muy atascado.

```
#------------------------------------
print("CODIGO")
codi=int(input(""))
print("DESCRIPCION")
des=input()
print("CANTIDAD")
canti=int(input())
di[codi]=((des,canti))
save=str(di[codi])
archivo = open("data.csv", "w")
archivo.write(save)
archivo.close()
print(di.keys())
#-----------------------------
print("BUSCAR")
search=int(input())
archivo=open("data.csv","r")
for x in archivo:
    if search==archivo[x]:
        print("yeah")
    print(x)
```

Comment: Ejemplo de datos del csv?

Comment: Y qué tiene de malo este código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando guardes en un archivo no es necesario que sea en formato de diccionario y menos aún si es un archivo scv , donde mayoritariamente se usa como separador ","

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
codi=input("Código: ") #es mejor alfanumérico
des=input("Descripción: ")
canti=input("Cantidad: ")
```

asignamos a variables lo ingresado

```
art = f"{codi},{des},{canti}\n"
```

generamos una cadena con los elementos separados por "," y agregamos un salto de línea, para que sea fácil de leer si después usas otra biblioteca, como pandas.

```
with open("data.csv", "a") as archivo:
    archivo.write(art)
```

el modificador del archivo es "a" para que agregue cada vez que lo uses, sino con "w" creara uno nuevo vacío

```
with open("data.csv") as archivo:
    linea=archivo.readlines()
```

leemos el archivo en forma de lista

```
dic = {}
```

definimos un diccionario vacío

```
for x in linea:
    lista = x.rstrip("\n").split(",") 
    dic[lista[0]]=[lista[1],int(lista[2])]
```

para cada elemento de la lista que es una cadena eliminamos el salto de línea y lo convertimos en una nueva lista. Agregamos al diccionario los valores de la lista

```
buscar = input("Código: ")
encontrado = dic.get(buscar)

if encontrado:
    print(f"Descripción: {encontrado[0]} Cantidad: {encontrado[1]}")
else:
    print(f"No existe el código: {buscar}")
```

por último buscamos el código en el diccionario.

No es ni por cerca la mejor forma, pero se aproxima a tu objetivo.